# Clustering trajectories using k-means

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis

I have several dataframes with coordinates that make up a line trajectory:
[image]

As can be seen from the dataframe the trajectory has several start and end coordinates, which looks like:

[image]

My question is how do I cluster trajectories, that are made up of several consecutive lines which connect to each other, using k-means clustering.

I have tried clustering stand alone lines such as these:

[image]

which have the following coordinates, where the end and start points are not the same:
[image]

Clustering such lines is not difficult and would be done in the following way:

```
X = np.array(df[['start_x', 'start_y', 'end_x', 'end_y']])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = "input your number of clusters")
kmeans.fit(X)
```

My problem is that I do not want to cluster such stand alone lines, but rather cluster several trajectories which are made up of connected lines.

is there a way to do that?

Comment: what is the data source?  there is not enough data to qualify for the law of large numbers